# Are there features (in particular, structured binding) which I can't use without 'auto'?

Tags: c++, c++17, auto, structured-bindings

`auto` keyword was introduced to simplify the code. In particular, iterating over stl containers became way easier and better-looking without having to use the ugly `std::vector<MyType>::iterator` syntax every time you want to loop over it. However, it was still possible to write code without using `auto` which would do exactly the same thing.

Now (I think) you can't use certain features without `auto`, in particular structured bindings:

```
std::tuple<int, int&> f();
auto [x, y] = f();
```

So, two questions:

1. Am I correct that there's no way to initialize `[x, y]` without using `auto` (still using structured bindings)? Is there a way to initialize it explicitly: `*explicit_type* [x, y] = f();`?
2. What other features require using `auto`?

Comment: Well there's always a [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to be considered... But its not one-to-one feature as e.g. it's an expression and not declaration...

Comment: It's not exactly required here, but there are places where the explicit type is not helpful, like `std::map<K,V>::insert_return_type i = m.insert(...);`

Comment: as for 2.: have you counted generic lambda? ...

Comment: also trailing return type demands use of `auto` keyword

Comment: @W.F. is there any case where trailing return type is *required* though?

Comment: @M.M maybe when it involves values of function template parameters itself not deduced types... not sure - you'd probably find counterexample though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct that there's no way to initialize `[x, y]` without using
>   `auto` (still using structured bindings)?

Yes, this is correct. The grammar specifies no other way, as can be seen for example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

> What other features require using `auto`?

A classical example should be the (generic) lambda expressions:

```
auto lambda = [](auto&&...) { };
```

But as stated in the comments, there are some other examples as well.

Comment: This compiles just fine though: `std::function<void()> f = [](){};`, so you're technically not required to use `auto` for lambdas. I am not sure if it's a valid counterexample though because they are indeed two different things. Is there some type conversion going on if I use std::function?

Comment: Well, what is your point then? If I create a function template, I can also just call it with a generic type without having to use `auto` and implement a way of type erasure.

Comment: @Valentin yes. A lambda is a dumb instance of a functor generated on the spot. An `std::function` is a heavyweight type-erased functionoid wrapper. You can stuff the former into the latter, but they are in no way equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

cppreference is quite clear concerning point **1/**, see [Structured binding declaration, C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

```
attr(optional) cv-auto ref-operator(optional) [ identifier-list ]
```

where `cv-auto` is possibly cv-qualified type specifier `auto`

For **2/** I have two examples:

1. the already cited `auto = [](){};`  lambda case
2. the other one is C++17 [Declaring non-type template arguments with auto](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html)

An usage example is:

```
template <typename Type, Type value> constexpr Type TConstant = value;
```

that can be simplified, in C++17, by:

```
template <auto value> constexpr auto TConstant = value;
```